# How to implement a generic method of the same interface in different ways?

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I defined the **Face** interface as following:

```
public interface Face {
    <R> LoadBalancer<R> create(List<R> resources);    
}
```

Then another interface `Type` and two classes which implement the `Face` interface.

```
public interface Type{}
```

This is the first implementation of `Face`  interface named **FaceImpl1**.

```
public class FaceImpl implements Face {

    @Override
    public <R extends Type> create<R> newLoadBalancer(List<R> resources) {
        return new SomeObject<R>(resources).
    }
}
```

Yet another implementation **FaceImpl2**

```
public class FaceImpl2 implements Face {

    @Override
    public <R> create<R> create(List<R> resources) {
        return new SomeObject2<R>(resources).
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to limit the generic type `R` to classes which implements the `Type` interface in the `FaceImpl1`, but in the class `FaceImpl2`, I do not need this limitation.

The problem is Java does not allow this. So in order to do this, how should I implement the two different classes? Or there are better ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by making the `interface` itself generic with a bounded type

```
interface Face<R> {

    List<? extends R> create(List<? extends R> resources);
}

public interface Type {
}

public class Impl implements Face<Type> {

    @Override
    public List<? extends Type> create(List<? extends Type> resources) {            
    }
}

public class Impl2 implements Face<Object> {

    @Override
    public List<? extends Object> create(List<? extends Object> resources) {
    }
}
```

Otherwise the method is not implementing the contract defined in the `interface` as the contract says "any type `R`" and you're making your method more constraining.

Just think what happens when someone does this:

```
final FaceImpl1 face1 = new  FaceImpl1();
final Face face = (Face) face1;
```

This is perfectly valid, but under your attempt you now lose any type restrictions.

If you add the type to the `interface` you will get a compiler warning because you would be casting a `Face<Something>` to a `Face` - i.e. the raw type.